# Intercept tap on Deletion control in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to intercept taps on the circular Deletion control ([example of Deletion Control button](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/822/schermata20100309a15070.png)) on my TableView to know when the "Delete" button comes in and I can change my cell layout. Can Anyone help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can handle "Delete" button appearance if you subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `-willTransitionToState` and/or `-didTransitionToState` methods there. Like:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state{
    if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
       // Delete button will appear
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for help but I use a simple ViewController to manage my tableviewcell and not a UITableViewCell. I suppose that this method don't work with a viewcontroller instead of UITableViewCell?

Comment: Don't forget to call super when overriding this method!!