# How can you select editingAccessoryView on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm putting a table view in edit mode, with `allowMultipleSelection = YES`. So, it puts those great circles on the left to indicate a row is or is not selected.

Pressing the cell does select the row. But pressing the circle does nothing.

I've set `cell.editingAccessoryView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` with no results.

Is there a property I'm missing or are we just not supposed to press the editingAccessoryView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If by "little circle" on the left, you mean the accessory view buttons on the right, then you need to implement the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Otherwise, if you are referring to the + and - icons then take a look at [UITableView : detecting click on '-' button in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448583/uitableview-detecting-click-on-button-in-edit-mode)

Comment: When the tableView is set to allow multiple section, the + and - icons on the left of the cell become circles that either have a check or are clear. This is the editingAccessoryView, and is what doesn't seem to accept a tap.

Comment: Those are not supposed to trigger additional events. Just tapping the row will mark them as checked.