# Click event for edit/delete button when tableview is in edit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6

I am showing my my table view in edit mode. So for all rows on left side of table view, there are delete button and by clicking on that it changes its image and showing "Delete" button on right side. I want click event for button available at left side. Please help.

Comment: Exactly, what button do you want to click? can you make a picture to describe your idea

Comment: Left delete button when tableview is in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your custom button as a subview then you can addTarget to your button like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Please be specific or show some screenshots. So that I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this without subclassing `UITableViewCell`. Please review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448625/2638425).