# Show/Hide accessory arrow when delete button disappears/appears in table view cell

Tags: ios, ios7

Is it possible to remove the accessory arrow when the delete button on right appears  when user clicks on the red circle button and then show it back when the delete button on right disappears.

I was able to remove the accessory arrow on clicking the red circle button by adding the following code in my custom cell class using the SO link - [UITableView : detecting click on '-' button in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448583/uitableview-detecting-click-on-button-in-edit-mode)

Code:-

```
(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)newState{
    [super willTransitionToState:newState];
    self.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    //deletebutton (minusbutton) will be animated in
    if(newState == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask){
        NSLog(@"UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask");
    }

    //deletebutton (minusbutton) will be animated out
    if(newState == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask){
        NSLog(@"UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask");

    }

    //deletebutton (minusbutton) will be rotated 90 degrees ccw
    if(newState == 3){
        NSLog(@"90 degrees ccw");

        self.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    //deletebutton (minusbutton) will be rotated 90 degrees cw
    if(newState == UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask){
        NSLog(@"UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask");


    }
}
```

My problem is I dont get the call when I click the cell in this methos or touches began and so I am not able to show the accessory view after the delete button hides

Comment: are you using some button on top right to transform tableview into edit mode or using swipe gesture on tableview cell ?

Comment: I am using the edit button on top right to transform at the moment. I will be adding the swipe to gesture in table view in future. Will that cause a difference?